# Dictionary throwing an Argument Exception even when protected by ContainsKey

Tags: c#, dictionary

In production, this code (C#, .NET 4.5.1) is throwing a `ArgumentException` stating that 
`An item with the same key has already been added.`

Code:

```
public MyClass()
{
   this.MyContent = new Dictionary<string, string>();            
}

public IDictionary<string, string> MyContent { get; private set; }

public void AddOrUpdateDictionary(string key, string value)
{
    if (this.MyContent.ContainsKey(key))
    {
        this.MyContent[key] = string.Concat(this.MyContent[key], value);
    }
    else
    {
        this.MyContent.Add(key, value);
    }
}
```

However, I can't recreate the error in a unit test. E.g. This behaves as expected -

```
[TestMethod]
public void AddOrUpdateDictionary_WhenAddingSecondValue_ValueIsAppended()
{
    const string InputValue1 = "Value1";
    const string InputValue2 = "Value2";
    string expectedValue = string.Concat(InputValue1, InputValue2);

    var obj = new MyClass();
    obj.AddOrUpdateDictionary("Key", InputValue1);
    obj.AddOrUpdateDictionary("Key", InputValue2);

    Assert.AreEqual(expectedValue, obj.MyContent["Key"]);
}
```

What is causing this? I thought the `ContainsKey` would've made the code safe.

Is this some weird threading gotcha I've missed? This code is on a model in an MVC site, no instances of it are static.

Comment: Are you using this from multiple threads? If so, there are various problems...

Comment: Most probably. Plain `Dictionary<K,V>` is not thread-safe, so another thread can add the key between your calls to `ContainsKey()` and to `Add()`. Something like [`ConcurrentDictionary<K, V>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd287191.aspx) would help with these issues.

Comment: Why not always just set `this.MyContent[key]` ? If it's a new key it will be added and otherwise overwritten

Comment: Is an instance of `MyClass` static?

Comment: @Me.Name for business reasons that are beyond the scope of the issue, the requirement is that an existing key is appended to, not overwrittern

Comment: @Me.Name: that's not working because he wants to concatenate the old value if available.

Comment: @TimSchmelter No, it's not static

Comment: Do you have an actual reproduction for that problem in your production environment? Thus, you can check if threading is a problem by locking the call and observing if the problem still exists. If you can't reproduce the error every time, it is a good hint for an threading related issue.

Comment: @TimSchmelter You're right, sorry NikolaiDante , didn't read thoroughly enough. Then locking is your safest bet. (btw, you could use TryGetValue to check if the value exists and obtain the value in one go)

Comment: @PatrikEckebrecht I haven't been able to recreate it on any other environment (local or otherwise) or via a Unit Test. It came to light as it's the dominant exception on a poorly production site during an analysis period.

Comment: Locking the dictionary won't be enough if you allow `MyContent` to remain accessible outside the class, since some other code could bypass the locking by calling `MyClass.MyContent.Add(...)`

Comment: There is also a ConcurrentDictionary (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd287191%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) . This thread safe dictionary has a nifty AddOrUpdate function that can help: `var dict = new ConcurrentDictionary<string, string>();
            dict["Abc"] = "abc";
            string value = "de";
            dict.AddOrUpdate("Abc", value, (key, curval) => curval + value);
            var s = dict["Abc"]; //abcde`

Comment: Another remark, making your dictionary public readable via get, one could change it without you to notice. It is highly discouraged to expose a mutable object. You could expose a read-only copy (`ReadOnlyDictionary`) of your `MyContent`.

Comment: @PatrikEckebrecht I agree totally. Tho I've checked all references and there's no adds being called currently. Tbh, there's a number of "silly things" that need fixing and refactorings I would implement if it was my code but that sort of work is beyond my advisory remit here. I've made a number of suggestions that have gone into the backlog, so hopefully they'll get picked up by the developers as part of their standard sprints. I'll add the suggestion in as to exposing it as ReadOnlyDictionary

Comment: KnowYourFeelBro. Thus, only multi-threading-issues seem to explain the problem. Having this portion of information, we cannot tell any further.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming the problem is thread related and it is allowed to change the type of dictionary, you could use a [ConcurrentDictionary](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd287191%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). It exposes a method ([AddOrUpdate](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee378664%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)) that can do exactly what's intended: either add the value or refactor the value based on the present value:

```
    class MyClass
    {
        public MyClass()
        {
            this.content = new ConcurrentDictionary<string, string>();
        }

        ConcurrentDictionary<string, string> content;
        public IDictionary<string, string> MyContent { get { return content; } }

        public void AddOrUpdateDictionary(string key, string value)
        {
            content.AddOrUpdate(key, value, (k, contentValue) => string.Concat(contentValue, value));   
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
You may want to use ConcurrentDictionary<T1, T2>
```

So it would be like:

```
    public void AddOrUpdateDictionary(string key, string value)
    {
        if (this.MyContent.ContainsKey(key))
        {
            this.MyContent[key] = string.Concat(this.MyContent[key], value);
        }
        else
        {
            this.MyContent.AddOrUpdate(key, value, (x, y) => value);
        }
    }
```

Comment: The ConcurrentDictionary alone is not enough if used like this. It can still be altered between the containskey and the update (and the obtaining of the value)